# Setup supervisor for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, supervisord

I am trying to monitor Elasticsearch processes using supevisor. So, I've installed supervisor and elasticsearch and I'm using AWS EC2 instance (ubuntu). But I'm not able to do configuration between supervisor with elasticsearch. I want to write elasticsearch.conf file in supervisor.

/etc/supervisor/conf.d/elasticsearch.conf

```
[program:elasticsearch]
command=sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch.service
directory=/usr/share/elasticsearch/
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=10
stdout_logfile=/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log
```

Is there any problem in my supervisor setup?
Want suggestions, could anyone guide how to do this?

Thanks!